# RedirectToAction does not have end response parameter. results in throwing 'Thread was being aborted" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I am working on MVC4 web application.

The current method **RedirectToAction** doesn't have an optional parameter to specify whether or not to end the response, whereas the Response.Redirect method does. Without setting the endResponse parameter to false (it is true by default), the thread gets aborted. This means every time I call RedirectToAction, I end up with a **"Thread was being aborted"** message in the event log.
This is explained here
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629

how to get workaround for this issue?

Comment: You mean, you get that event log entry when you try to do something after returning RedirectToAction from your controller?  In the "normal" flow, where your controller method returns RedirectToAction(), it should not be appearing in the event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have got fix for this. 
before this i have some recommendations when you have long running process

1) Use Fix mentioned in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629

2) Try to move long running code out of IIS, try to use service which will run in background.

For those who cant change existing code here is quick and dirty solution.

**Increase idle time out in IIS (app pool of your application => right click=>advanced setting ) in minutes to whatever you think enough to complete the long running process.**